# ASP.NET Core API bind multiple object types from body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using `.net core sdk v3.0.101`

**Scenario**

An incoming POST request will contain a collection of object types in its body using the following structure:

```
{
    "object-collection": [{
            "type": "ClassA",
            "properties": [
                "name": "First object type",
                "code": "CODE_1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "ClassB",
            "properties": [
                "name": "Second object type",
                "tag": "TAG_1",
                "is-valid": "true"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The important point here is that in practice there are approximately 100 types that could be included in the request payload.

I've got models defined for each `type` specified in the request above, these look like this:

```cs
public class ClassA
{
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [MaxLength(255)]
  public string Tag { get; set; }

  public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

**Objective**

I'm trying to find the best way to bind the request body to these classes so I can get the benefits of the model validation attributes

**What I've tried**

I first looked at using [Custom Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1), but I didn't feel like that was the correct way to proceed as I couldn't see how you could get the model to bind based on an attribute value in the request body

I've thought about just binding to a very simple model, something like this:

```cs
public class PayloadModel
{
  [Required]
  public string ObjectCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Then looping through the JSON data to find the Class by the `type` attribute value and then binding to a new instance of the class.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateObjectCollection([FromBody]PayloadModel objectCollection)
{
    // Send a command off to deserialize the JSON string into the various objects

    // Do other stuff
}
```

**Questions**

1. Can Custom Model Binding be used to achieve what I've described?
2. If not, is there a cleaner way to do this that I haven't considered?

Thanks in advance - let me know if I can provide any more info

Comment: Usually when accepting FromBody, I create a special ViewModel for that purpose alone.

Answer (score 0):

I would just split these items into individual collections so you don't have to deal with type conversion issues:

```
public class PayloadModel
{
  public List<ClassA> ClassACollection { get; set; }
  public List<ClassB> ClassBCollection { get; set; }
}
```

```js
var payload={
    "object-collection": [
        {
            "type": "ClassA",
            "properties": {
                "name": "First object type",
                "code": "CODE_1"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "ClassB",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Second object type",
                "tag": "TAG_1",
                "is-valid": "true"
            }
        }
    ]
};

var mappedPayload=payload["object-collection"].reduce((combined,item)=>{
   if(!combined[item.type+"Collection"]) combined[item.type+"Collection"]=[];
   
   combined[item.type+"Collection"].push(item.properties);
   return combined;
},{});

console.log(mappedPayload);
```